# Selenium getting value by skipping a tag in between

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

## This is from Redbus.in website

What i want to do is extract the travels list and store it in list..but I cant get the exact value from this.

```
<div id="t1-trvDiv" class="trvDiv" style="display: block;"> 
   <ul id="t1-travListing" class="ul-listing">
     <li id="t1-travls-0">
     <li id="t1-travls-1">
       <a title="National Travels" title1="1" onclick="bindTrav("t1",1);">
         <span class="tickSelected"></span>
         National Travels
       </a>
     </li>
     <li id="t1-travls-2">
       <a title="Seabird Tourists" title1="2" onclick="bindTrav("t1",2);">
         <span class="tickSelected"></span>
         Seabird Tourists
       </a>
     </li>
     <li id="t1-travls-3">
       ...
     </li>
```

This is the java code I used to at least print the first value..

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='t1-travListing']/li"));
int i=0;
allElements.remove(allElements.size()-1);
for (WebElement element: allElements) {
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='t1-travls-0']/a/")).getText());        
}
```

As there is span tag after  tag i don't know how to skip that and get value from that

Comment: What exactly do you want to extract? The text?

Comment: What i want to do is from this page I want to save all the values from Travels dropdown into a List http://www.redbus.in/Booking/SelectBus.aspx?fromCityId=123&fromCityName=Chennai&toCityId=462&toCityName=Mumbai&doj=21-Dec-2013&busType=Any&opId=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this. This should work.

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='t1-travListing']/li"));
int i=0;
allElements.remove(allElements.size()-1); // not sure why are you doing this
for (WebElement element: allElements) {
    System.out.println(element.findElements(By.xpath("./a")).getText());        
}
```

Comment: Thats not working .returning null values only. also getText is available only for findElement not findElements   instead I tried the following . this is working.                                         `int travel=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='t1-travListing']/li")).size()-1;
for(int i=0;i<travel;i++) System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='t1-travls-"+i+"']/a[@title]")).getAttribute("title"));                                       `

Comment: ya it is working.as I used the title attribute to get the value

Answer (score 0):

You can select your nodes directly with xpath:

```
//ul[@id = 't1-travListing']/li/a
```

Using it with findElements, it will return a list of all a-Tags within li-tags.
Selenium's getText should get you the displayed text, doing the "skipping" of the empty span-Tags by itself:

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id = 't1-travListing']/li/a"));

for (WebElement element: allElements) {
    System.out.println(element.getText());        
}
```

You could also try an expression like this to select not the elements, but the text in them:

```
//ul[@id = 't1-travListing']/li/a/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

This would also work for you

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'t1-travls')]"));
            for (WebElement element: allElements) {
                System.out.println(element.getText());        
            }
```

or

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[onclick*='bindTrav']"));
            for (WebElement element: allElements) {
                System.out.println(element.getAttribute("title"));        
            }
```

Comment: can you try the second option?

Comment: It means onclick containing text